# Facebook API Application Permissions

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I want to write application which allows me to send video on Facebook wall.

1. I was writing app in Winforms C#.
2. I was creating application in Facebook developers (without Platform, just simple application).

For my credidentials everything works fine. But when I'm using another, I've got information that application doesn't has permissions to post on Facebook. In Winforms app I set permissions: publish_actions, manage_pages. I've heard that my Facebook app must ask for these permissions. To do this, I must to create web page. I don't want to create web page for review, because I don't have time for that and I can't write pages. Is there any way to just send movie to Facebook after login in Winforms application? I thought this should be easy, but for now, it's a nightmare. Please, help me.

Comment: Facebook now has much more anti-trash filters. This means the user has to **manually** click on "Accept" on the permissions to write to their wall.

Comment: When I run my application, user must accept it. But I don't know how to give my application permissions for posting on wall without creating special page for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.